# Umask settings for users=rwx, group=r, others=

Tags: umask

How can i set the umask in ubuntu for permissions like this:

users = rwx
group = r 
others =

I tried this mask, but it didn't work:

```
umask 011
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote the `manpage` (`man umask`):

> ```
> For example, the following default ACL
>        is equivalent to a umask of 022:
>
>            u::rwx,g::r-x,o::r-x
> ```

So for your goals, you need to do the math of `777 - (OCTAL value of expected permissions)` to get the `umask` (this is octal math of course, so not the easiest)

The permissions you want on your specific folder(s) or files is `740` (`u::rwx,g::r--,o::---`). `777 - 740` results in an octal value of `037`.  You need to use a `umask`, then, of `037`.

Note that you may want to tread lightly here using this as the 'default' umask - some things might not be able to reach into folders and files and such.

Comment: @2019 because folders have slightly different 'permission structure' than files.  the `+x` bit for instance permits entering into the directory and traversing it.  But for files, the `+x` bit indicates whether the file is executable or not.